# Waterproof/resistent cutouts

Tags: water-resistance

I've searched a lot but found nothing.

I am fairly new to 3D printing but I know how to print waterproof cases (choosing the right filament and settings).

What I am wondering is how about I/O (Input/Output) e.g. displays, LEDs, buttons, and connectors (ports).

How can I use these parts and how to seal them, etc.?

What other ways do users usually choose for I/O?

Comment: why do you want to seal them? You can't print underwater

Comment: Can you tell us more about your application? Waterproof, like weather resistant, or waterproof, it’s going to be literally underwater?

Comment: Does this fit your application https://www.instructables.com/3D-Printing-Make-Water-Tight-and-Air-Tight-Contain/

Comment: @ChinchillaWafers Thx for asking! I mean water resistent. Imagine e.g.  an Outdoor Soil Moisture Sensor with some buttons.